# Проблемы со слайдером при масштабировании страницы

Tags: javascript, слайдер

друзья, если не сложно подскажите кто знает ответ.Слайдер работает замечательно, при отдалении тоже, но если обновить страницу после отдаления происходит такая ситуация как на видео, получается что слайдер сразу улетает куда то далеко до белого фона.Кстати в FireFox улетает даже без отдаления, работает только первый слайд.
Ниже ссылка на видео и код:

HTML

```
<!-- slider -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__slider">
        <div class="shops__window">
            <div class="shop__titles">
                <div class="shop__title">Магазин</div>
                <div class="shop__sale-title">Скидка</div>
            </div>
            <div class="shops__window-line"></div>
            <div class="current__shops-container">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="slider__inner">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container__slider {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 440px;

}

.slide {
    height: 440px;

}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    /* justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
}


.shops__window {
    position: absolute;
    top: 461px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 310px;
    height: 325px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.shop__titles {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.shop__title {
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-top: 19px;
}

.shop__sale-title {
    margin-left: 124px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    color: #2DB346;
}

.shops__window-line {
    border: 1px solid #EEF0F7;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.current__shops-container {
    width: 306px;
    height: 257px;
}

.current__shop {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.current__sale {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.current__shop-active {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(45, 179, 70, 0.8);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);

}

.street {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    width: 207px;
}
```

JS

```
// slider

    function mainSlider() {
        const currentShop = document.querySelectorAll('.current__shop'),
            wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
            slideGround = document.querySelector('.slider__inner'),
            slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
            width = window.getComputedStyle(wrapper).width,
            street = document.querySelectorAll('.street'),
            sale = document.querySelectorAll('.current__sale');


        let slideIndex = 1,
            offset = 0;


        slideGround.style.width = 100 * slides.length + '%'; // Размер ширины блока со всеми слайдами
        slideGround.style.display = 'flex'; // Выстраивание всех слайдов по горизонтали
        slideGround.style.transition = '0.5s all'; // Плавное переключение слайдов

        wrapper.style.overflow = 'hidden';

        // Устанавливаем всем слайдерам одинаковую ширину
        slides.forEach(slide => {
            slide.style.width = width;
        });

        function addDataAtribute(n) {
            for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                n[i].setAttribute('data-slide-to', i + 1);
            }
        }

        addDataAtribute(currentShop);
        addDataAtribute(street);
        addDataAtribute(sale);

        function removeNumbers(str) {
            return +str.replace(/\D/g, '');
        }

        currentShop.forEach(shop => {

            shop.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const slideTo = e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to');

                slideIndex = slideTo;
                offset = removeNumbers(width) * (slideTo - 1);
                slideGround.style.transform = `translateX(-${offset}px)`;


            });
        });
    }
    mainSlider();
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l3pLS086RDwpF3MzZVIRU7uOkLrfHw3U/view?usp=sharing  <- ссылка на видео
Буду рад любому совету, спасибо:)

Еще такой вопросик, может кто в курсе, есть еще один слайдер, у которого меняется не сам слайд в данный момент а динамически созданный в js контент, это новостной блок на сайте, хочу сделать что бы так же менялось изображение background-image, что бы у каждого блока с контентом была своя картинка, но проблема в том, что эта картинка находится в главном контейнере новостного блока, а все остальное, весь интерфейс и т.п расположены поверх нее, как лучше поступить в данной ситуации?

так же прилагаю ссылку на проект на гитхабе, где вы можете сами все понажимать, попробовать и посмотреть, оба вопроса относятся к одному проекту. https://mathiasmichaelweiss.github.io/mega_brand/?

Премного благодарен за внимание.